# how to retrieve Checkbox checked event stored in database

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, state

I am just missing few line of code in my project. I have checkboxes and submit button. User clicked in the checkbox and on click he will filter the the options. I am storing checkboxes checked result into database as a serialize array and the retreving it as a unserialize array so i am getting the filter checkbox result properly whenever i refresh the page. The only problem is my checkboxes are not showing checked when i refresh the page. It showing the result properly and stored into database but i am not able to maintain the checkbox event. I think i am missing 1 line of code in html input type.My unserialize array are stored in $config variable.
Here is my code:
html code:

```
    if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle-edit')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        0   => array( 'FAHRZEUGE','enabled',$page['script'],''),
        1   => array( 'EDIT-FAHRZEUGE','aktiv',$page['script'],'',''),  
    );

    $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                    '.CreateMessage().'
                    <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">
                        <table id="FAHRZEUGE" >
                            <tr>
                                <td>';
    <table id="FAHRZEUGE" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder" checked />
                                    <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder</label><br>

                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" value="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked />
                                    <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label><br>

                                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" checked />
                                    <label for="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern">Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern</label><br>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="Herausforderungen" id="Herausforderungen" value="Herausforderungen" checked />
                                    <label for="Herausforderungen">Herausforderungen</label><br><br>                

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            </table>
$html .= '</td>
                    </tr>
                        </table>
                        '.CreateButton($page['button']).'
                    </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

php code :

```
    if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle')
{
    $page['register-fahrzeuge'] = array(
        1   => array( 'FAHRZEUGE','aktiv',$page['script'],''),
        0   => array( 'EDIT-FAHRZEUGE','enabled',$page['script'],'',''),    
    );        

            /*when empty default config...
            $query=    "SELECT dashboard_widget.configuration FROM dashboard_widget WHERE Id =1"; 
            */ 

           $query ="SELECT dashboard_widget_users.configuration
                                         FROM dashboard_widget_users
                                         INNER JOIN yw_user ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user = yw_user.intern
                                         INNER JOIN dashboard_widget ON dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_dashboard_widget = dashboard_widget.id
                                         WHERE dashboard_widget_users.dsnr_yw_user=".$user_id." AND dashboard_widget.id=1 ";  
                    $result = mysql_query($query, $myConnection);               


        $html = '<table width="538" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div>'.CreateRegister($page['register-fahrzeuge']).'</div>
                '.CreateMessage().'
                <div class="cont-liste-verlauf register">';
                    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                        $empty_config=$row['configuration'];
                        if(empty($empty_config )) {
                            $sql="SELECT dashboard_widget.configuration FROM dashboard_widget WHERE Id =1";
                            $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $myConnection);
                            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);  
                            $config= unserialize($results['configuration']);                            
                        }
                        else{
                        $config= unserialize($row['configuration']);
                        }

                        foreach($config as $val)
                        {
                            if($val == 'Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_ohne_Bilder')
                            {

                                $sql='SELECT count( * ) as bilder FROM autodo.amo_bilder_live l LEFT JOIN autodo.afzdaten a ON l.dsnr_afzdaten = a.dsnr WHERE l.dsnr_afzdaten IS NULL';
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result); 
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['bilder'];

                            }
                            else if($val == 'Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as Preis FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE Preis IS NULL';
                                            $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                            $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                            $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['Preis'];
                            }
                            else if($val == 'Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as fehler FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE fehler IS NULL';
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['fehler'];

                            }
                            else if($val == 'Herausforderungen')
                            {
                                $sql='SELECT count(*) as herausforderung FROM autodo.afzdaten WHERE herausforderung IS NULL'; 
                                $sql_result=mysql_query($sql);
                                $results=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result);
                                $configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] = $results['herausforderung'];
                            }                       

                            if($configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'] > 0)
                            {
                                $html .= '<a href="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['link'].'" style="color:red;">'.'<image src="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['image'].'" width="30" height="25" align="middle">.'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['count'].' '.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['linkName'].'<br>'.'<br>'.'</a>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $html .='<span style="color:green;">'.'<image src="'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['image'].'" width="30" height="22" align="middle">.'.$configVehicleWidget[$val]['textAllOK'].'<br>'.'<br>'.'</span>';
                            }                           
                    }
                }

                $html .= '              
            </div>          
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $return = array(
        'status' => 1,
        'html'  => $html
    );

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output "checked" if your checkbox is checked, and not , if it is not checked.

The "checked" value is already retrieved from the database (there is no need to use session in this case).

Here is one way to do it:

```
<?php

$is_checked = true;

if ($is_checked)
{
    // checked

    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" checked />
    <?php
}
else
{
    // not checked

    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" />
    <?php
}


?>
```

Here is a more compact way to do the same thing:

```
<?php

$is_checked = true;

// this will output either "checked" or nothing ""
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="a" ' . ($is_checked ? 'checked' : '') . ' />';


?>
```

**Edit: Here is an example of how to retrieve the $is_checked value from a DB.**

Create a test table and fill it with sample data, with this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
`user_id` int(11),
`checkbox_name` varchar(256),
`is_checked` int(11)
);


INSERT INTO test (`user_id`, `checkbox_name`, `is_checked`)
VALUES
('1', 'a', '0'),
('1', 'b', '1'),
('1', 'c', '0'),
('2', 'a', '0'),
('2', 'b', '1'),
('2', 'c', '1')
;
```

Retrieve the data with PHP:

```
<?php

function is_cb_checked ($user_id, $checkbox_name)
{

    $q = mysql_query ('select * from test where user_id = ' . (int)$user_id . " and checkbox_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($checkbox_name) . "'" );

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($q);

    $is_checked = ($row['is_checked'] > 0 ? true : false);

    return $is_checked;
}


$user_id = 2;


$a_is_checked = is_cb_checked ($user_id, 'a');
$b_is_checked = is_cb_checked ($user_id, 'b');
$c_is_checked = is_cb_checked ($user_id, 'c');


echo 'a = <input type="checkbox" name="a" ' . ($a_is_checked ? 'checked' : '') . ' /><br/>';
echo 'b = <input type="checkbox" name="b" ' . ($b_is_checked ? 'checked' : '') . ' /><br/>';
echo 'c = <input type="checkbox" name="c" ' . ($c_is_checked ? 'checked' : '') . ' /><br/>';
```

Comment: Hi i tried to do the same way but its not working ...can you please tell me how it will know by using just $is_checked=true that my checkbox is cheked or not from database ? please check ur modified answer...

Comment: I edited my answer and added a sample code for retrieving the checkbox value from a db

Comment: i think there is mis-confusion i am storing my checkbox checked results in the form of array in database and retreving it from unserialized way its working properly just need to show which checkbox is checked so that i can maintain the state even after page refresh.In if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle') condition i have my unserailize array stored in $config variable....just want to use that variable to checked which checkbox has checked in if($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle-edit') function...

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to change this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" checked />
```

to something like this, not sure what you checkbox values look like when you take them out the DB

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" id="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" value="Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern" <?php echo (isset($config['Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern'])) ? 'checked="true"' : ''; ?> />
```

Basically tell it if your checkbox was checked, apply the checked attribute otherwise don't, I imagine they are always checked right now.

Of course you will need to pull the database stuff out before creating the html output.

Comment: please check the modified code now the checkbox are also not showing...can you please tell me where i m doing mistake ? and my array are stored in $config variable  so should i put into session variable and checked for input type checkbox ?

Comment: you don't have php tags and echo, or did they just not show <?php echo ... ?>, never mind i see they are a string, now.

Comment: i am writing this code inside php so i cant use php tag inside php...i have put html code inside php var ...

Comment: why, are you doing ajax for the form? or normal page reload when submitting it.

Comment: are you missing the ending } on foreach($config as $val) or is that just a copy paste error.

Comment: hi i think wht you have written i made changes in that but now checkboxes are not showing :(. (isset($config['Fahrzeuge_mit_Fehlern']) is written in different fucntion in php and the html code is written in another fucntion so i cant just use it ur statement .

Comment: what do you mean function? file?

Comment: your changed code is saying to only create the <inputs if they are in the session array, not to check and un-check them, are the values in the session?

Comment: I am not using session but i think may be need to use here ? please check the updated question...now my unserialize array in which i have checkbox checked result is stored in $config which is in ($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle') and the input type checkboxes are in ($param['aktion'] == 'get-widget-vehicle-edit') so how can i show now which checkboxes are checked ? Just a small mistake i am doing :(

Comment: u have written right statement...i am just using wrong condition please do u knw how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all the checkboxes on page load,
you may use javascript in 
$( document ).ready()
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;